# Get topic metadata from KafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka

I have seen from the KafkaTemplate implementation that there is no access to the actual Kafka Producer. While this Producer wrapping might be good, there are some methods from the Kafka Producer that are needed like `metrics()` and `partitionsFor(java.lang.String topic)`.
In KafkaTemplate we could have these same methods wrapping the actual Kafka Producer methods.
Is this something likely to be implemented in newer versions?
Could I implement it and make a pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with Kafka guidelines, the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` always returns the same producer, so it's safe to call `createProducer` to get a reference to the single producer.

Calling `close()` on the producer is ignored.

However, I have opened a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/180) to provide access to the producer from the template.